# Marketing Cloud Simple Query with filter Bad Request - Need Help

Tags: query, error-messages, filters, marketingcloudapi

I am making the following REST GET call:

```
https://{{et_subdomain}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets?$page=1&$pagesize=50&$orderBy=AssetType asc&$filter=AssetType.Views.Content eq 'Holiday'&$fields=AssetType,Views,Content
```

I receive the following 400 bad request:

```
{
"message": "Error retrieving asset collection: GetItemCollection: (400) 
   search_phase_execution_exception - Type: search_phase_execution_exception Reason: \"all 
 shards failed\"",
"errorcode": 30001,
"documentation": ""
```

}

I desire to search through all content for the string Holiday.

I am using Postman and it is automatically adding %20 where there are spaces and %27 for the single quotes.

Comment: adding %20 where there are spaces and %27 for the single quotes is expected url encoding.

Comment: This is the URL that Postman sends of course the domain is ours: 
GET {https://domain.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/asset/v1/content/assets?$page=1&$pagesize=50&$orderBy=AssetType%20asc&$filter=AssetType.Views.Content%20eq%20%27Advisor%27&$fields=AssetType,Views,Content}

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2021/04/explore-the-salesforce-marketing-cloud-apis-with-a-postman-collection

Comment: I am using the exact same endpoint ( except search criteria is different ) and yet I receive the error Bad Request. This same request worked fine on 10/25/21. Has anything changed on the REST API since October 25th?